# Sending and inserting per class container values Independently and separately. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found a way to send a ajax request per class container call dataContainer. The problem I am facing is how can I send and insert per dataContainer values separately and independently from all

dataContainers? I google around and I could not find any way to do this I know this is possible I will really appreciate any code advice that is given.

I want to be able to press the button in each dataContainer and send the input values in each dataContainer independently and separately without all the other dataContainers being triggered to page x.php.

Currently it's only getting the first dataContainer input values.

Here's the code

**index.php**

```html
<style>
    .dataContainer{
      background-color: red;
      width: 185px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dataContainerDesign #a,#b,#send{
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }
    </style>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.dataContainer #send').click(function(){
     //Per data container
     var $dataContainer = $(this).next('.dataContainer');
     //
     
        //Var data structure
        var a= $('.dataContainer #a').val();
        var b= $('.dataContainer #b').val();
        //
        
        //Data to be sent
        var Data= {
          a: a,
          b: b
        }
        //
        
        //Result after sending 
        var Result= function(success){
       $dataContainer.html(success);   
        }
        //
        
     //Request
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: Data,
          url: 'x.php',
          success: Result
        });
     //
     
      });
    });
    </script>
    
    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input id='a' type='text'>
      <input id='b' type='text'>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->
    
    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input id='a' type='text'>
      <input id='b' type='text'>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->
    
    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input id='a' type='text'>
      <input id='b' type='text'>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->
    
    <div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
      <input id='a' type='text'>
      <input id='b' type='text'>
      <button id='send'>Send</button>
    </div><!--</dataContainer>-->
```

**x.php**

```
<p style='display: inline-block;'>
<?php
$a= $_POST['a'];
$b= $_POST['b'];
echo 'Sent Values: ';
echo $a.','.$b;
?>
</p>

<?php

/*<Insert values into Data Base>*/

$db_servername = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'jd';
$db_password = '1234';
$db_name = 'xxx';

$db_connect = new mysqli($db_servername, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

$db_query = "INSERT INTO sometable (a,b) VALUES ('$a','$b')";

$db_result= $db_connect->query($db_query);

/*</Insert values into Data Base>*/

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `id` attributes to `class`.

```js
$('.dataContainer .send').click(function() {
  //Per data container
  var $dataContainer = $(this).closest('.dataContainer');

  //Var data structure
  var a = $dataContainer.find('.a').val();
  var b = $dataContainer.find('.b').val();

  //Data to be sent
  var Data = {
    a: a,
    b: b
  };

  console.log(Data);

  //Result after sending 
  var Result = function(success) {
    $dataContainer.html(success);
  };

  //Request
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: Data,
    url: 'x.php',
    success: Result
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='dataContainer dataContainerDesign'>
  <input class='a' type='text' value="test1">
  <input class='b' type='text' value="test2">
  <button class='send'>Send</button>
</div>
<!--</dataContainer>-->
```